# Determinar si un número pertenece a la serie fibonacci java

Tags: java

tengo un problema en mi código y es que se debe de determinar si un número pertenece a la serie fibonacci, pero debo preguntarle al usuario si despues de agregar un numero desea añadir otro, tengo este código, pero solo funciona una vez, al ingresar otro número no determina si es de la serie o no, espero sus respuestas, gracias...

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner entrada=new Scanner(System.in); 
         int num1=0, num2=1, temp, limite,contador = 0,num;
         String r="";


         do{
             System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: ");
         limite=entrada.nextInt();   
         while(num2+num1<=10000){          
             temp=num1;          
             num1=num2;           
             num2=temp+num1;
             if(limite==num2){
                 contador=contador+1;    
             }
         }
         System.out.println("Quiere ingresar otro numero?");
         r=entrada.next();
         }while(!r.equals("no"));    


         System.out.println("Los números que coincidieron con la secuencia fibonacci fueron: "+contador);








        // TODO code application logic here


}
```

Answer (score 0):

los valores de num1 y num2 deberian iniciarse dentro del do while ya que la primera vez que ingresas un nùmero estos valores cambian y cuando ingresas el segundo nùmero los valores de num1 y num2 van a ser probablemente mucho mayores q el nùmero que ingresaste y no va a coincidir en la serie. el codigo quedaria asi:

```
 Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num1 , num2 , temp, limite, contador = 0, num;
        String r = "";

        do {
            System.out.println("Ingrese un numero: ");
            limite = entrada.nextInt();
            num1 = 0;
            num2 = 1;
            while (num2 + num1 <= 10000) {
                temp = num1;
                num1 = num2;
                num2 = temp + num1;
                if (limite == num2) {
                    contador = contador + 1;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Quiere ingresar otro numero?");
            r = entrada.next();
        } while (!r.equals("no"));

        System.out.println("Los números que coincidieron con la secuencia fibonacci fueron: " + contador);
```